# Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am a beginner in ionic 1. I created an app prototype in ionic creator and imported it on my pc. Now I want to add sqlite database with it. But, while I tried to implement it the console shows below error:

```
ionic.bundle.js:26799 TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
    at ChildScope.$scope.insert (controllers.js:18)
    at fn (eval at compile (ionic.bundle.js:27643), <anonymous>:4:209)
    at ionic.bundle.js:65429
    at ChildScope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30400)
    at ChildScope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30500)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:65428)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (ionic.bundle.js:16792)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:16780)
    at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2953)
    at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2942)
```

I have a separate controller page. Here's my controller code snippent.

```
angular.module('app.controllers', ['ngCordova'])



.controller('salesCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', // The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams,$cordovaSQLite) {

      if (window.cordova) {
      db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "pos.db" }); //device
     console.log("not in browser");
    }else{
      db = window.openDatabase("pos.db", '1', 'my', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // browser
      console.log("browser");

    }
           $scope.insert=function(){
                    var query="INSERT into items(firstname,lastname) VALUES(?,?)";
                    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query,["firstname","lastname"]).then(function(result){

                        console.log("INSERT ID:"+result.insertId);
                    },function(error){
                            console.log(error);
                    })
                }

}])
```

And here is my app.js code snippet:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform,$cordovaSQLite) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
// DATABASE SECTION STARTS
    if (window.cordova) {
      db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "pos.db" }); //device
     console.log("not in browser");
    }else{
      db = window.openDatabase("pos.db", '1', 'my', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // browser
      console.log("browser");

    }

        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items(id integer primary key,firstname text,lastname text )");

        //DATABASE SECTION ENDS

      // db=$cordovaSQLite.openDB({name:"pos.db"});
      });
    })
```

Comment: Glad to help you =) Cheers m8

Comment: :) facing some more issues.. Posted another question.. Would u take a look at that?

Comment: I did but iam that familiar with $cordovaSQLite. Maybe I going to take a look in it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject `$cordovaSQLite` into your controller in the right way and you should be fine:

```
 .controller('salesCtrl', [
      '$scope', 
      '$stateParams', 
      '$cordovaSQLite', // <- this was missing
      function ($scope, $stateParams, $cordovaSQLite) {
          //put all your logic here
      });
```